ArXiv submission on hold for 11 days. Should I inquire via moderation support or wait longer?
I submitted my paper to arXiv on June 28th. The status changed from “processing” to “submitted” that same day, and then to “on hold” the next day.
While on hold, the primary category changed to “None” and what I had originally selected for the primary category is now in the cross listed categories. I realize now that the category I selected may not be the best choice, but I am unable to update the category while on hold.
This is a time-sensitive paper. Should I contact support or continue waiting? I am considering sending an inquiry message to moderation user support, but I've read inquiring about 'on hold' status can trigger a rejection.

This question is similar to: Submission on hold on arxiv. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I know of a paper that had been on hold for several weeks before the process became slower in mid-2022. An author contacted arXiv moderation, arXiv moderation reminded the responsible moderators, and the problem got resolved shortly after that. I don't know whether the author's message triggered the reminder and the reminder triggered the resolution.

Update: it got posted 17 days after submission!

@dlnB did you contact arXiv? or just waited?

I played it safe and just waited

Searching this site: https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=arxiv+on+hold
suggests to me that it's not unusual to be in the "on hold" state for several weeks. It's not really arXiv's business what your deadline is or the time sensitivity. You can make the paper available through whatever other means are available to you in the meantime for most purposes.
If you're wanting it to be on arXiv because you perceive something on arXiv has having more legitimacy than something posted on, say, your personal website, well, their review process is really the only thing to justify that with, so you might as well be patient and let the review run its course.

Valid point. Really appreciate your answer!

Several weeks seems to be the reality in some cases, but the arXiv website says "several days" here, so contacting them after more than several days seems okay.
